# 'Area code not set' issue in my UpgradeData Script

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, cli

i've written some upgrade-scripts for the database. When I'm running 
    setup:upgrade 
from the CLI, I'm getting following error:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\SessionException]                       
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.  
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
Area code is not set
```

I tried the following areacode stuff in my UpgradeData-File with all possible area codes:

```
<?php
namespace ***\Catalog\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $_product;
    private $_productAction;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct( EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action, \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState, $name=null )
    {
        $appState->setAreaCode('admin');
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_productAction = $action;
    }

    public function upgrade( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context )
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( [ 'setup' => $setup ] );
        $setup->startSetup();

        if( $context->getVersion() && version_compare( $context->getVersion(), '2.0.6' ) < 0 )
        {
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute( 4, 133, 'hide_price', 0 );
        }


        if( $context->getVersion() && version_compare( $context->getVersion(), '2.0.5' ) < 0 )
        {
            $attrData = array( 'hide_price' => 0, );

            $productIds = $this->_product->getCollection()->getAllIds();
            $this->_productAction->updateAttributes( $productIds, $attrData, 0 );
        }


        if( $context->getVersion() && version_compare( $context->getVersion(), '2.0.4' ) < 0 )
        {
            $eavSetup->addAttribute( \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'hide_price', [ 'type' => 'varchar', 'backend' => '', 'frontend' => '', 'label' => 'Preis verstecken', 'input' => 'boolean', 'class' => '', 'source' => '', 'global' => \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, 'visible' => true, 'required' => false, 'user_defined' => false, 'default' => '', 'searchable' => false, 'filterable' => false, 'comparable' => false, 'visible_on_front' => false, 'used_in_product_listing' => true, 'unique' => false, 'apply_to' => '' ] );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

But nothing helps.

When I'm running the upgrade, the schema-version in the database gets updated but not the data_version.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance
- Ali

Comment: Could you please post the full code of your class ?

Comment: If I delete the following injected Objects `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action` it works

Comment: Please edit your question with the full UpgradeData file code

Comment: done //edited my question

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$productIds = $this->_product->getCollection()->getAllIds();` with some hard coded ids like `$productIds = [1,2,3];`? The product collection probably tries to instantiate a customer session to get customer group prices, but I am not sure where the session instantiation for this happens in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before and i solved it by try{} catch{}, try this code

```
<?php
namespace ***\Catalog\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $_product;
    private $_productAction;
    protected $state;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct( 
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action, 
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        $name=null 
    ) {

        $this->state = $appState;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_productAction = $action;
    }

    public function upgrade( ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context )
    {
        try{
            $this->state->getAreaCode();
        }
        catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $ex) {
            $this->state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
        }

        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( [ 'setup' => $setup ] );
        $setup->startSetup();

        if( $context->getVersion() && version_compare( $context->getVersion(), '2.0.6' ) < 0 )
        {
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute( 4, 133, 'hide_price', 0 );
        }


        if( $context->getVersion() && version_compare( $context->getVersion(), '2.0.5' ) < 0 )
        {
            $attrData = array( 'hide_price' => 0, );

            $productIds = $this->_product->getCollection()->getAllIds();
            $this->_productAction->updateAttributes( $productIds, $attrData, 0 );
        }


        if( $context->getVersion() && version_compare( $context->getVersion(), '2.0.4' ) < 0 )
        {
            $eavSetup->addAttribute( \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'hide_price', [ 'type' => 'varchar', 'backend' => '', 'frontend' => '', 'label' => 'Preis verstecken', 'input' => 'boolean', 'class' => '', 'source' => '', 'global' => \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, 'visible' => true, 'required' => false, 'user_defined' => false, 'default' => '', 'searchable' => false, 'filterable' => false, 'comparable' => false, 'visible_on_front' => false, 'used_in_product_listing' => true, 'unique' => false, 'apply_to' => '' ] );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: should be marked as the answer, correct way to handle this

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your upgrade script is not properly coded.

First, I **don't think you have to specify the area code in your constructor and as the class does not extend anything, you don't have to call the parent constructor.**

Thus you can replace:

```
public function __construct( EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action, \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState, $name=null )
{
    $appState->setAreaCode('admin');
    parent::__construct($name);
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->_product = $product;
    $this->_productAction = $action;
}
```

With:

```
public function __construct( EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action $action)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->_product = $product;
    $this->_productAction = $action;
}
```

On top of that you should **start the setup before doing anything else** so replace:

```
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( [ 'setup' => $setup ] );
    $setup->startSetup();
```

With:

```
    $setup->startSetup();
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create( [ 'setup' => $setup ] );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I mentioned before, if I remove the `product` and `action` part, it works fine.